# Freeze a property in DataMapper Model

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

Consider I have this following model definition, I want a particular property which should be constant from the moment it has been created

```
class A
  property :a1, String, :freeze => true
end
```

Is there something like this? or may be using callbacks ?

Comment: You want to have the property assignable only once? Via the initializing attribute hash and or the attribute writer? Should the property value be frozen after first assignment?

Comment: yes exactly, it should be assignable for the first time after that it shud be frozen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class YourModel
  property :a1, String

  def a1=(other)
    if a1 
      raise "A1 is allready bound to a value"
    end
    attribute_set(:a1, other.dup.freeze)
  end
end
```

The initializer internally delegates to normal attribute writers, so when you initialize the attribute via `YourModel.new(:a1 => "Your value")` you cannot change it with `your_instance.a1 = "your value".`. But when you create a fresh instance. `instance = YourModel.new` you can assign once `instance.a1 = "Your Value"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to assign the constant, then

```
property :a1, String, :writer => :private

before :create do
  attribute_set :a1, 'some value available at creation time'
end
```

may suffice

Comment: I throws this error while creating a new record "private method `type=' called for #<MyModel:0xba176b4>", If by some means we can add this attribute after creating the record then it'd suffice, as in after :create do (**make writer private here**) end

Comment: I've updated my answer with how you could initialise the property, but I don't think it's what you want (readable, assign once, must be present)